# What happens to long running clickhouse updates if the client dies?

Tags: jdbc, clickhouse, distributed-database

Column type modifications in clickhouse can take a long time, since clickhouse has to migrate all data to the new type. Let's say a jdbc client initiates a column type update, and then the jvm process is killed. What happens to the update task? Please link to official sources if possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a [mutation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/#mutations) the process is asynchronous and will continue in the background - assume it has been scheduled once the server responds. Use the [system.mutations](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/system-tables/mutations) table to monitor progress of the execution.

You can kill the operation using [KILL MUTATION](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/kill#kill-mutation)